# Get all groups of an facebook user

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, passport.js

I'm trying to create in nodejs a page that will list all the facebook groups of am user which is logged in with passportjs facebook strategy. The problem is that in the v2.5 facebook removed the `user_groups` permission (is now deprecated), and I can only get the groups the user admins with `user_managed_groups` permission.

How can I make a scrapping tool that gets all the groups the user is a member of? I read something about using scrapy, but I need to log the user again.

Is there any other way to get all the groups?

Answer (score 0):

Scraping is not allowed on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

You can only get groups you manage, as you already found out. There is no legal workaround for this.